# Parsing xpath empty array

Tags: php, xpath

I have an array generated using the simplexml_load_file method, but unfortunately there are duplicates that I have to remove. For this I use xpath and I am removing duplicate values in the foreach based on the code_on_card attribute. Unfortunately, but after applying xpath I get an empty array. The error is in the path, or maybe in the further code?

```
<offer file_format="IOF" version="2.6" extensions="yes">
    <products>
        <product id="8" producer_code_standard="GTIN13" code_on_card="KR001 B">
        </product>
    </products>
</offer>
```

And PHP code with not working tried

```
$XML = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$productlist = $XML->xpath("/offer/products/product/@code_on_card");

foreach ($productlist as $duplicate) {
    unset($duplicate[0]);
}

print_r($productlist);
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you attached the original XML rather than a dump of the loaded object.

Comment: Already, I showed a fragment of the original XML of course truncated to relevant information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code your using, doesn't check for duplicates at all, it actually finds all nodes and just removes them.

First - create an array for the codes you've already encountered.  Then as you process each product, check if it's already been processed.  If it has, then remove it from the document.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$XML = simplexml_load_file('NewFile.xml');
$productlist = $XML->xpath("/offer/products/product");

$prod = [];
foreach ($productlist as $product) {
    $code = (string)$product['code_on_card'];
    if ( in_array($code, $prod)) {
        unset($product[0]);
    }
    else    {
        $prod[] = $code;
    }
}

echo $XML->asXML();
```

I've used this as a test file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offer file_format="IOF" version="2.6" extensions="yes">
    <products>
        <product id="8" producer_code_standard="GTIN13" code_on_card="KR001 B">
        </product>
        <product id="8" producer_code_standard="GTIN13" code_on_card="KR001 A">
        </product>
        <product id="8" producer_code_standard="GTIN13" code_on_card="KR001 B">
        </product>
    </products>
</offer>
```

And the output is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offer file_format="IOF" version="2.6" extensions="yes">
    <products>
        <product id="8" producer_code_standard="GTIN13" code_on_card="KR001 B">
        </product>
        <product id="8" producer_code_standard="GTIN13" code_on_card="KR001 A">
        </product>

    </products>
</offer>
```